# How can i run a php script on activating a plugin in joomla?

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

I am creating a new plugin. I want to run a php script at the time of plugin activation (only once, that script must never run again). For example register_activation_hook in wordpress. How can I do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to [Joomla Events Tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3aPlugins), has some useful stuff.

First of all you should use System plug-in, here is [Joomla System Plug-in tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Reference%3aSystem_Events_for_Plugin_System).

You need to identify the event at which you need to execute your script. I will use `onAfterInitialise` which is the first system event.

Algo: create a plug-in with config parameter that will trigger the plug-in only once. You can also create a separate db table with configs for you param and query/update fields in that table instead. When plug-in is triggered for the first time execute custom code and set lock to prevent from executing in future..

Code:

#### XML Param

```
<params>
     <param name="executeOnInitialize" type="radio" default="1" 
        label="Execute on Init" description="Executes custom code on System onAfterInitialise">
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </param>
</params>
```

#### PHP Plug-in Method

```
function onAfterInitialise()
{
    if ($this->params->get('executeOnInitialize', 0) == 1){
          // TODO: execute custom code. You can package dirs with code into your plug-in install file. Then you can `require_once` files and use them.

          // TODO: updated the executeOnInitialize = 1 in the plug-ins table
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that can let you run the script on plugin enabling. You could save in a separate file a flag  that tells you if it is the first time the plugin is run.